# Correct usage of Subscriber.onStart

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm considering using [Subscriber.onStart](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Subscriber.html#onStart()) to show a progress indicator which is then hidden in [onCompleted](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observer.html#onCompleted()).

```
private class MySubscriber extends Subscriber<Boolean> {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Boolean aBool) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

The nice thing about this is that the progress indicator is completely coupled to the lifecycle of the subscriber. I'm not completely sure if this is this methods intended usage. The javadocs only mention backpressure and "useful initialization". One problem I've seen with this approach is that if the Observable that I'm observing happens to have a [delaySubscription](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#delaySubscription(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) somewhere, then `onStart` won't be called until after the delay, which is bad if it's a progress indicator.

The alternative is to show the progress indicator before subscribing to the Observable. This works, but spreads the responsibility for the progress indicator around.

Is it correct to use `onStart` for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is acceptable usage for `onStart` if you are happy with the effects of delayed subscription.

An alternative might be to add an `initialize()` method to `MySubscriber` and call that before subscribing, or even call your initialization logic in the constructor of `MySubscriber` (though you have to be careful with this sort of usage so that the reference to self doesn't escape).